I am migrating from XML to JSON feed in SP APIs, but when I am submitting a JSON feed I am getting error
I am submitting below feed:
{
  "header": {
    "sellerId": "XXX",
    "version": "2.0",
    "issueLocale": "en_US"
  },
  "messages": [
    {
      "messageId": 1,
      "sku": "7ASDDDD",
      "operationType": "PATCH",
      "productType": "PRODUCT",
      "patches": [
        {
          "op": "replace",
          "path": "/attributes/fulfillment_availability",
          "value": [
            {
              "fulfillment_channel_code": "DEFAULT",
              "quantity": 9
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

but getting error:
{
  "header": {
    "sellerId": "XXX",
    "version": "2.0",
    "feedId": "323990020003"
  },
  "issues": [
    {
      "messageId": 1,
      "code": "BAD_REQUEST",
      "severity": "ERROR",
      "message": "Invalid parameters provided."
    }
  ],
  "summary": {
    "errors": 1,
    "warnings": 0,
    "messagesProcessed": 1,
    "messagesAccepted": 0,
    "messagesInvalid": 1
  }
}


Did you make any progress with this? I am now also trying to upload stock data via the API. Would you mind sharing how you are sending the data / what endpoints etc?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79260786/how-to-check-status-of-uploaded-inventory-json-to-amazon-via-selling-partner-ap
